# I don´t know how to initialize atributes in this constructor

Tags: java

I have the next code, and this code has to validate a date, but there are some requirements that i have to follow:

First of all i have to create a class named MyDate, this class contains three attributes: day, month and year. I have to initialize these attributes with a constructor without parameters.

Then I have to define three methods: setDay(),setMonth() and setYear(), inside this methods i have to validate if a date is correct. In the main method() i have to invoke the set methods, but the problem is that i don´t know how to initialize the attributes with the constructor, while at the same time i am already initializing them in the main when i call the set methods

```
class MyDate{
    final int JANUARY = 1;
    final int FEBRUARY = 2;
    final int MARCH = 3;
    final int APRIL = 4;
    final int MAY = 5;
    final int JUNE = 6;
    final int JULY = 7;
    final int AUGUST = 8;
    final int SEPTEMBER = 9;
    final int OCTOBER = 10;
    final int NOVEMBER = 11;
    final int DECEMBER = 12;

    private int day;
    private int month;
    private int year;

    public MyDate(){
        //here is the problem;
    }

    public int getDay()
    {
        return day;
    }

    public int getMonth()
    {
        return month;
    }

    public int getYear()
    {
        return year;
    }

    public boolean setDay(int day)
    {
        //is not finished
    }

    public boolean setMonth(int month)
    {
        //is not finished
    }

    public boolean setYear(int year)
    {
        //is not finished
    }
}

public class E{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        MyDate date = new MyDate();
        date.setDay(31);
        date.setMonth(11);
        date.setYear(2014);
        System.out.println("DAY: "+date.getDay());
        System.out.println("MONTH: "+date.getMonth());
        System.out.println("YEAR: "+date.getYear());
    }
}
```

Comment: You can call the setter methods from within the constructor, and pass in some default value.

Comment: if you want to initialize them through Setters it's not need to do anything in constructor

Comment: And Also, You do not need to Make 12 variables just to set the months,you can use single String array and store it there.

Comment: @PaulRichter it could be a solution, but one of the requirements say: Define the atributes of the object instantiated through its three methods(setDay,setMonth,setYear)

Comment: @user3105533 I doubt you would be penalized if you did it that way as its a very normal and common thing to do. It would be the equivalent of telling you to put clothes on, and assuming you would include pants in that solution, but shorts would be just as good if you so chose. But if you really wanted to avoid that, you can simply initialize them directly ex: `year = 0`, just as Frosty's answer demonstrates below. Note that primitive values such as `int` are already initialized by default to zero anyways, so technically this step is redundant if you're merely defaulting it to zero.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I totally understood what you want, particularity the part where you want to set the variables in a constructor without parameters. How about the following solution? You can create a default Constructor as well and call `this(1, 1, 2015)`.

```
class MyDate {

   public MyDate() {
       this(1, 1, 2015);
   }

   public MyDate(int day, int month, int year){
       setDay(day);
       setMonth(month);
       setYear(year);
   }

public void setDay(int day) {
   if (isValid(day, month, year)) 
      this.day = day;
   else 
     throw new RuntimeException("Day is not valid.");
}

private boolean isValid(int day, int month, int year) {
   // Your validation logic should go here.
}
```

Similar to `setDay` you can define `setMonth` and `setYear` for setting day and month. Your validation logic should go into `isValid`.

Comment: Thanks @Ali, this could be a solution but the constructor must be without parameters, it is a requirement

Comment: @user3105533 you can remove the constructor with parameters and inside the other one, set the properties, is it an assignment?

Comment: Yes it is an assignment

Comment: @user3105533 tell your teacher the whole assignment doesn't really make sense. Validating the properties in the setters is not a good practice: the object may be in an inconsistent state. Why not making MyDate immutable?

Comment: Yes, i will tell him that, i´ll ask him why do I have to use the setters instead of doing it with the constructor

Answer (score 0):

Your design is poor from 2 points:

#### First problem:

Having separate setters allows the state (fields) to be invalid until all setters are called. This is bad. Also bad is if you change from 31 Mar to 28 Feb (both valid), but happen to change the month first, the date is temporarily invalid (31 Feb). Also bad.

The 3 fields should be set *atomically* (in one action) using one method that sets all 3.

#### Second problem:

You have setters! Make your class *immutable* (no setters, final fields). If you need to "change" a date, make a new one. String works like this - it will work for you too.

```
class MyDate{
    final int JANUARY = 1;
    final int FEBRUARY = 2;
    final int MARCH = 3;
    final int APRIL = 4;
    final int MAY = 5;
    final int JUNE = 6;
    final int JULY = 7;
    final int AUGUST = 8;
    final int SEPTEMBER = 9;
    final int OCTOBER = 10;
    final int NOVEMBER = 11;
    final int DECEMBER = 12;

    private final int day;
    private final int month;
    private final int year;

    public MyDate(int d, int m, int y) {
        day = d;
        month = m;
        year = y;
    }

    public int getDay() {
        return day;
    }

    public int getMonth() {
        return month;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public boolean isValid() {
        // put your impl here
    }
}

public class E {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        MyDate date = new MyDate(31, 11, 2014);
        System.out.println("DAY: " + date.getDay());
        System.out.println("MONTH: " + date.getMonth());
        System.out.println("YEAR: " + date.getYear());
    }
}
```

If you want, you could add a line to the constructor to allow only valid dates:

```
if (!isValid())
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
```

Comment: I totally agree with you on both points (especially the first), but from what they said, it seems they've been explicitly asked to define setter methods (which also seem to perform validation). They may not have a choice.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an Example on initializing Variable using Constructor:

Checked if it is **FEBRUARY** and Change Day Limit to **28**, If False define max day to **30~31**

```
class MyDate{    
    private int day;
    private int month;
    private int year;

    public MyDate(){
        this(1,1,2014);
    }

    public MyDate(int day, int month, int year){
        this.day = day;
        this.month = month;
        this.year = year;
    }

    public int getDay()
    {
        return day;
    }

    public int getMonth()
    {
        return month;
    }

    public int getYear()
    {
        return year;
    }

    public boolean setDay(int day)
    {
        if(month == 2){
             if(day>0 && day <=28){
                 this.day = day;
                 return true;
             }else{
                  return false;
             }
        }else{
             if( month % 2 != 0){
                 if(day>0 && day <=31){
                      this.day = day;
                      return true;
                 }else{
                      return false;
                 }
             }else{
                 if(day>0 && day <=30){
                      this.day = day;
                      return true;
                 }else{
                      return false;
                 }
             }
        }
    }

    public boolean setMonth(int month)
    {
        if(month>0 && month <=12){
            this.month = month;
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean setYear(int year)
    {
      // Not Required
        if(year>1993 && year <=2018){
            this.year = year;
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}

public class E{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        MyDate date = new MyDate();
        date.setDay(31);
        date.setMonth(11);
        date.setYear(2014);
        System.out.println("DAY: "+date.getDay());
        System.out.println("MONTH: "+date.getMonth());
        System.out.println("YEAR: "+date.getYear());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have to initialize these attributes with a constructor without parameters.

Unless you are required to provide an explicit starting value for these parameters, you're pretty much done with that step already.  Java will [set an initial value for your fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5), so each of those `int`s are set to 0 by the time you type `new MyDate()`.

If you *are* required to start at specific values, then put them directly into the body of the no-arg constructor.

```
public MyDate() {
    this.year = 2015;
    this.month = 1;
    this.day = 7;
}
```

> I don't know how to initialize the attributes with the constructor, while at the same time I am already initializing them in main when I call the set methods

This is how [POJOs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object) work, in a sense.    You create some class that does have a decent number of fields, but you only set the ones you care about.

Because you can rely on the initial value guarantee provided by the Java Language Specification, you don't have to worry about initializing those values unless you require them to be an explicit initial value besides zero.

Answer (score -1):

If you can't pass any parameters to the constructor then all you can really do is initialize the object's variables to zero. The object won't contain a valid date, however, until you call your set methods which contains the validation code. The main reason for doing this is to avoid "variable might not have initialized" errors.

```
public MyDate(){
    year = 0;
    month = 0;
    day = 0;
}
```

Just make sure that the validation code for setDay checks that the month and year don't equal zero still, otherwise it will be impossible to determine if the day value is valid.

Comment: You don't need to do that, necessarily.  Java will [initialize integers to 0 by default](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5).

Comment: @Makoto It is a Null Pointer Exception when you do not specify it to Zero. Maybe your using a different compiler that is why you said it will automatically set value to zero.

Comment: @deadlydragon00: First, that's a quote directly from the ***language*** spec.  I trust that it's pretty authoritative in these situations.  Second, you will ***NEVER*** get a `NullPointerException` when messing with a ***primitive***.

Comment: Ok I get now your Point, It was the IDE who force the Programmer to specify Zero before Compiling. I guess I am pretty wrong in this part- Thanks for the info.